# Removing HH:MM:SS from MYSQL Result

Tags: mysql, sql, date

SQL query returns the following:

```
    User Registered On     Last visit
    2011-10-08 23:51:08    2011-10-08 23:51:09
    2007-07-28 16:26:57    2013-10-05 11:51:42
```

I want to truncate the result to only YYYY-MM-DD so I can compare the login dates to see if the user is somewhat active. I've looked at CAST and SUBSTRING, but I just can't get things to work!

How would I remove the HH:MM:SS from the result? Tearing my hair out over this!

```
$query = "select * 
FROM    users
";

$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>" . "User Registered On" . "</td><td>" . "Last visit" . "</td></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo "<tr><td>" . $row['registerDate'] . "</td><td>" . $row['lastvisitDate'] . "</td></tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
mysql_close();
```

Comment: use `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['registerDate']))` in php

Comment: You can use date_format in mysql query

Comment: You could use `SELECT date(registerDate) as rDate, date(lastvisitDate) as lvDate...` and return only what you need

Answer (score 3):

Try

In php way:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['registerDate']))
```

In mysql way : use `DATE_FORMAT()`, `DATE()`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(registerDate, '%Y-%m-%d'), DATE_FORMAT(lastvisitDate, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM users;
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL use [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function on your datetime column